# How to properly manage an Activity height and the height of its added fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

My fragment has a textview whose text contains links and each time the link is clicked I do a fragment transaction to add a new instance of the same fragment.

To explain further I have ActivityA which hosts fragmentA.

FragmentA fetches text from the web. The text contains links. When a link in fragmentA is clicked, a callback to ActivityA starts a new Instance of FragmentA 
which fetches another text once more.

These are my codes:

**ActivityA**

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentA.OnLinkClickedListener {

    private final String TAG = "ActivityA";
    Fragment mContent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rock);

        String rock_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("rockId");
        Log.d(TAG,  rock_id);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            Fragment fragment;

            fragment = new FragmentA();
            bundle.putString("rock_link", rock_id);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_out_right, android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            ft.add(R.id.rock_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mContent = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "mContent");
        }

    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mContent != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent", mContent);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void OnLinkClicked(String link) {
        Log.d(TAG, "The activity got the url and it is " + link);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        Fragment fragment;

        fragment = new FragmentA();
        bundle.putString("rock_link", link);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        //ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right, android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        //ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.add(R.id.rock_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

**FragmentA**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    OnLinkClickedListener mLinkClickedListener = sLinkCallbacks;

    private AlertDialog internetDialog;
    private AlertDialog sthWrongAlert;
    private String url;

    private String rockData;

    private final String TAG = "FragmentA";
    protected com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader mImageLoader;


    TextView rockContent;
    private String rock_content;

    public FragmentA() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView called");
        url = getArguments().getString("rock_link");
        Log.d(TAG, "Rock url is " + url);
        view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);
        showDialog();
        sthWrongDialog();


        rockContent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drock_content);


        DisplayImageOptions defaultoptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .build();
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getActivity())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultoptions)
                .writeDebugLogs()
                .build();


        mImageLoader = com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance();
        mImageLoader.init(config);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {


            rockData = savedInstanceState.getString("rockData");
            if (rockData != null) {
                parseHtml(rockData);
            } else if (NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(getActivity())){
                loadRock();
            }



        } else {
            if (NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(getActivity())) {
                //Calling method to load rocks
                loadRock();
            } else {
                internetDialog.show();
            }
        }
        return view;
    }


    public interface OnLinkClickedListener {
        public void OnLinkClicked (String link);
    }

    private static OnLinkClickedListener sLinkCallbacks = new OnLinkClickedListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnLinkClicked(String link) {

        }
    };


    private void showDialog() {
        internetDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                ...
    }

    private void sthWrongDialog() {
        sthWrongAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                ...
    }




    private void loadRock() {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadRock called");

        final ProgressBar progressBar;
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Log.d(TAG, "You clicked rock id " + url);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    // The usual codes for volley string request
                    //parseHtml() is called in onResponse
                });

        //Creating requestqueue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

        //Adding request queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }

    private void parseHtml(String response) {
        Log.d(TAG, "parsinghtml");
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(response);
        rock_content = document.select("div.entry-content").first().html();

        rockContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    protected void makeLinkClickable(SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder, final URLSpan span)
    {
        int start = strBuilder.getSpanStart(span);
        int end = strBuilder.getSpanEnd(span);
        int flags = strBuilder.getSpanFlags(span);
        ClickableSpan clickable = new ClickableSpan() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Do something with span.getURL() to handle the link click...
                Log.e(TAG, "on click" + span.getURL());
                String clickedLink = span.getURL();
                mLinkClickedListener.OnLinkClicked(clickedLink);

            }
        };
        strBuilder.setSpan(clickable, start, end, flags);
        strBuilder.removeSpan(span);
    }

    protected void setTextViewHTML(TextView text, String html) {
        CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(html, new UILImageGetter(rockContent, getActivity()), null);
        SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);
        URLSpan[] urls = strBuilder.getSpans(0, sequence.length(), URLSpan.class);
        for(URLSpan span : urls) {
            makeLinkClickable(strBuilder, span);
        }
        text.setText(strBuilder);
        text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mLinkClickedListener = (OnLinkClickedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnLinkClickedListener");
        }
    }
}
```

**Layout for FragmentA**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@android:color/white">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        tools:context=".ActivityA">


        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progress_circle"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dviewbottom"
            android:hint="@string/main_body"
            android:textColorLink="@color/textlink"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/drock_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

**Layout for ActivityA**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/rock_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</ScrollView>
```

Like I wrote above,  when I click on the link in  rockContent inside FragmentA, ActivityA launches a new instance of FragmentA.

The problem is that this new Instance of FragmentA still has the height of the former Instance. And after the data has been loaded, there's is either an empty space at the bottom or the text is truncated depending on the size of the former instance.

To further explain, before the data is loaded into the new fragment, I can scroll up and down since the height is still that of the old instance of the fragment.

Please how do I correct this? i.e. to make each new instance of the fragment to have the height of the phone screen as I have set in the layout?

**EDIT**

If I set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` in the FrameLayout of FragmentA layout, the problem is solved i.e. no extra space or truncating. The problem with this is that the Progressbar is not centered on the screen anymore. It's positioned just below the ActionBar.

Comment: Did you try to set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and then modify the gravity of the progressbar to center?

Comment: @MachoProgrammer I tried but no diffrence.